# What does String[]::new (or) Byte[]::new mean?

Tags: java, java-8

I can see from java8 docs that `::new` is used to refer to the constructor method.

But when it comes to this statement,

```
stream.toArray(String[]::new)
```

what does `String[]::new` mean? There shouldn't be a class named `String[]` which is very lame and I could not interpret what it is actually meant for.